# Harddrive bootable from EFI and BIOS

Tags: linux, macintosh

I have an external harddrive with Linux loaded onto it that I use with my home PC (BIOS enabled). When I try to boot into this harddrive on my Mac (EFI), it doesn't show up as an option. Is there any way I can reformat the harddrive so that it is bootable both from my PC and Mac machines? I couldn't find much on the web for how I would be able to do this.

Comment: Mac & newer PC use UEFI. Many PC vendors still call it BIOS, but Microsoft required UEFI with gpt partitioning since Windows 8 released in 2012. Is external drive gpt partitioned? And does it have an ESP - efi system partition? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy

Comment: The external drive is MBR partitioned and has a Fat32 system partition. I've done some additional research and it seems like I must change the drive to be GPT partitioned. Is this the case? And does doing this require me to reset the drive completely?

Comment: There is this tool. But good backups requires & since UUIDs & GUIDs change, bootloaders & mounts of any partitions in fstab have to be updated. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I recently switched the harddrive to being GPT Partitioned and installed the rEFInd bootloader. Now I can boot the harddrive on my Mac, however my PC does not have a UEFI support, so I cannot boot the disk from my PC. Is there a solution so that I can boot my disk with EFI on Mac and Legacy BIOS on my PC? Would this require two bootloaders? I am pretty unexperienced in this area.

Comment: You need grub-pc with a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot on gpt and grub-efi-amd64 with an ESP for UEFI boot. I believe you can install both grub, but with updates may get grub out of system, so always need flash drive to make repairs. There are these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227221/simple-hand-made-persistent-usb-that-boots-either-bios-or-uefi & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative-18.04.1 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083330/how-to-make-an-usb-ubuntu-installation-more-compatible-with-different-computers/1083812#1083812

Answer (score 0):

I used the process described here https://askubuntu.com/a/1083577/1251110 to successfully make an external hard-drive that boots on both Legacy BIOS and EFI (Macs).

Note: If you follow the process described here, make sure you are using a Legacy BIOS computer. I am not sure if this is always the case, but if you are on EFI and complete the installation process it might download  Grub to your main OS. I made this mistake on my first attempt.